# Incorrect output with np.random.choice

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I am trying to randomly select records from 17mm dataframe using np.random.choice as it runs faster compared to other methods but I am getting incorrect value in output against each record...example below:

```
data = {
  "calories":[420,380,390,500,200,100],
  "Duration":[50,40,45,600,450,210],
  "Id":[1,1 2,3,2,3],
  "Yr":[2003,2003,2009,2003,2012,2003],
  "Mth":[3,6,9,12,3,6],
}
df = PD.dataframe(data)

df2=df.groupby(['id','yr'],as_index=False).agg(np.random.choice)
```

Output:

```
Id yr   calories    duration    mth
1  2003    420    50    6
2  2009    390    45    9
2  2012    200    450   3
3  2003    500    210   6
```

Problem in the output is for Id 3 for calories 500, duration and mth should be 600 and 12 instead of 210 and 6...can anyone please help why it is choosing value from different row ?

Expected output:

Same row value should be retained after random selection

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because Pandas applies aggregates across each column independently, try putting a print statement in, e.g.:

```
def fn(x):
  print(x)
  return np.random.choice(x)

df.groupby(['id','yr'],as_index=False).agg(fn)
```

would let you see when the function was called and what it was called with.

I'm not an expert in Pandas, but using [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) seems to be the easiest way I've found of keeping rows together.

Something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "calories":[420,380,390,500,200,100],
  "duration":[50,40,45,600,450,210],
  "id":[1,1,2,3,2,3],
  "yr":[2003,2003,2009,2003,2012,2003],
  "mth":[3,6,9,12,3,6],
})

df.groupby(['id', 'yr'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1))
```

produces:

```
     calories  duration  id    yr  mth
0 1       380        40   1  2003    6
1 2       390        45   2  2009    9
2 4       200       450   2  2012    3
3 5       100       210   3  2003    6
```

the two numbers at the beginning are because you end up with a multi-index. If you want to know where the rows were selected from this would contain useful information, otherwise you could discard the index.

Note that there are warnings in the docs that this might not be very performant, but don't know the details.

Update: I've just had more of a read of the docs, and noticed that there's a [`GroupBy.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) method, so you could instead just do:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'yr']).sample(1)
```

which would presumably be performant as well as being much shorter!